# Why brack an rval

Tags: c

Please see the following snippet of C code:

```
PM_RAISE(retexn, exn)
        do
        {
            retexn = (exn);
            gVmGlobal.errFileId = __FILE_ID__;
            gVmGlobal.errLineNum = (uint16_t)__LINE__;
        } while (0)
```

On the 4th line, why is `exn` surrounded by brackets?

**EDIT** (In reply to `IntermediateHacker`) Here is the original snippet of code:

```
#if __DEBUG__
#define PM_RAISE(retexn, exn) \
        do \
        { \
            retexn = (exn); \
            gVmGlobal.errFileId = __FILE_ID__; \
            gVmGlobal.errLineNum = (uint16_t)__LINE__; \
        } while (0)
#else
#define PM_RAISE(retexn, exn) \
        retexn = (exn)
#endif
```

Comment: It's probably some macro or definition. Show more code.

Comment: looks like a macro-definition to me, so could you reformat it properly including the `#define`?

Comment: is this a macro? have you omitted the `#define` and the \s?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: I've added some more code. I cannot see more that is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just considered good practice to wrap macro arguments in brackets. It doesn't help much in your example, but say you had:

```
#define multiply(a, b) a * b
```

and used it with:

```
multiply(4 + 3, 2)
```

it would expand to

```
4 + 3 * 2
```

which is obviously not the expected result (3 would be multiplied by 2 first).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is guess work on my part, but I think it's to enable entering an arithmetic expression as `exn`.

Here's what I mean:

```
/ * If I use: */
PM_RAISE( whatever, 18 / 9 + 5 );

/* It will generate */
whatever = (18 / 9 + 5);

/* which is good. */
```

Also, it's good practice to include brackets in macro functions like @James has pointed out.

Comment: Without the brackets it'd just be `whatever = 18 / 9 + 5;`. What's wrong with that?